# Visual Studio 2010 not deploying XSL file to SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So I have a SharePoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010 and I have defined a fldtypes_*.xsl file.  I put the file into a mapped directory /Template/Layouts/XSL, however, when I deploy the application using Build->Deploy , the file is not copied.

I can copy the file manually, and it works great, but there must be a way to make it copy with the regular deployment process.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: when you select the file's properties, what is the deployment type for them?

Comment: The DeploymentType is "TemplateFile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was I had added a mapped folder to "Layouts", then just added the XSL folder underneath that, expecting it to be deployed along with the rest of the stuff in the layouts folder.  That is not the case.

I added a mapped directory directly to the XSL folder and deployed and it works fine.  Not sure why the previous setup didn't work, as that's the way it is shown in all the examples, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer to your .xsl file, using relative path:

`"/_XSL/path/to/xslFile.xsl"`

I assume you chose Add -> SharePoint Mapped Folder... but TEMPLATES and LAYOUTS were not added when you selected the XSL folder, hence there were not added to the folders tree in the project.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.  Could you provide a more thorough explanation?

Comment: I guess you found a solution, but what I meant was related to the folder structure when right-clicking on the project's name to add a mapped folder, such as layouts.